# keras Sequential() crashes kernel

Tags: python, keras, sequential

Just run a few lines with keras Sequential() crashes jupyter notebook kernel. Firstly it was GPU memory which reached all volume (no matter it is 3090 with 24 Gb). Then I took some precauses like

```
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
```

and VRAM stops to push the limit. But the kernel still crashes. Here the code:

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM,Dense
cl=np.random.rand(200).reshape(-1, 1)
def processData(data,lb):
    X,Y = [],[]
    for i in range(len(data)-lb-1):
        X.append(data[i:(i+lb),0])
        Y.append(data[(i+lb),0])
    return np.array(X),np.array(Y)
X,y = processData(cl,7)
X_train,X_test = X[:int(X.shape[0]*0.80)],X[int(X.shape[0]*0.80):]
y_train,y_test = y[:int(y.shape[0]*0.80)],y[int(y.shape[0]*0.80):]
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64,input_shape=(7,1)))
```

At last line the kernel dies. I dont' know what is the problem. My keras and tenserflow versions:
2.4.3 and '2.5.0-dev20210312' respectively. Cuda spec:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:32:27_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

I guess it is 3000x cards and their compatibility with Cuda and nn libraries problems. Nevertheless I haven't any problem with yolov5 library.

Comment: I have no idea why and whether this is related, but when I used Jupyter Notebook it crashes when I attempt to run PyTorch torchvision module as well. But the code runs well on Google Colab, so I think  maybe the problem is in JN itself.

Comment: @seraph yeah) it is blows my mind

Comment: My question has no answers as well, maybe should send a ticket to Jupyter Notebook official

Comment: @seraph Hi! I tried to run .py file in anaconda prompt and got 'Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found' so I uninstall CUDA 10.2 (which was the only way with 3080 card) and install 11.3 (which indeed was advised as the only choose with 3000x series at some place) which suprisingly works fine with 3090. And both .py and JN now run without error or VRAM out of limit. So the cure for my is to update CUDA to 11.3 version.

Comment: i see, thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run .py file with same code in anaconda prompt and got 'Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found' so I uninstall CUDA 10.2 (which was the only way with 3080 card) and install 11.3 (which indeed was advised as the only choose with 3000x series at some place) which suprisingly works fine with 3090. And both .py and JN now run without error or VRAM out of limit. So the cure for me is to update CUDA to 11.3 version